# Angular lazy routing ignoring parent path

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6.1 and I tried to set up an app module and a feature module (called entities module) using lazy routing. I want to create a route **/entities/list**, linking to a component inside my entities module. But I can't get this route to work. Instead, the component will be displayed when I navigate to **/list**. Why is my routing ignoring the parent "**/entities**" path?

app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {EntitiesModule} from './entities/entities.module';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, EntitiesModule],
    providers: []
})

export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'entities', loadChildren: './entities/entities.module#EntitiesModule'},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: 'app <router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

entities/entities.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {EntitiesRoutingModule} from './entities-routing.module';
import {EntitiesComponent} from './entities.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [EntitiesComponent],
    imports: [EntitiesRoutingModule]
})

export class EntitiesModule {}
```

entities/entities-routing.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {EntitiesComponent} from './entities.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'list', component: EntitiesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class EntitiesRoutingModule {}
```

entities/entities.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-entities',
    template: 'entities'
})

export class EntitiesComponent {}
```

I also tried defining the route in the entities module using the following, but the component will still be shown navigating to **/list**, not to **/entities/list**.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', children: [
            {path: 'list', component: EntitiesComponent}
        ]
    }
];
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to do lazy loading. However, you are doing eager loading.

In `app.module.ts` the line:

imports: [AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, `EntitiesModule`],

is loading the Entities module. Remove it from there for lazy loading and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the lazy loaded module as a child.

```
  {
    path: 'entities',
    children: [{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './entities/entities.module#EntitiesModule'
    }]
  }
```

Comment: That worked as well, thanks a lot! I accepted Pankaj's answer, because it also solves my buggy lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

As you are lazy loading the module but does not initializing the Entities component. Your /entities/list should be the child of entities component

Your entities/entities-routing.module.ts should be like

```
const route: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: EntitiesComponent, children: [
  { path: 'list', component: EntitiesListComponent }, // here should be your /entities/list path which i think you haven't made any
  { path: 'xyz', component: XYZComponent }, // entities/xyz and so on...
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'}
 ]}
];
```